# Handling Time over TimeZones

Tags: c#, datetime, utc

I am attempting to convert this string time value `2017-01-10T13:19:00-07:00` to local time (Eastern).  Now from my research `07:00` is `Mountain Time` which is 2 hours beind `Eastern Time` (my local).  However, when I run this syntax to convert the returned output is `01/17/2017 10:19:00 AM` which is 3 hours difference, not 2.

This is my syntax I am using, is this set-up incorrectly?  What should I change in order to have the accurate local time returned from the UTC time?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string green = "2017-01-10T13:19:00-07:00";

    DateTime iKnowThisIsUtc = Convert.ToDateTime(green);
    DateTime runtimeKnowsThisIsUtc = DateTime.SpecifyKind(
        iKnowThisIsUtc,
        DateTimeKind.Utc);
    DateTime localVersion = runtimeKnowsThisIsUtc.ToLocalTime();
    Console.WriteLine(localVersion);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**EDIT**
I have verified my computer is set to the correct time zone by using the following syntax which produces Eastern for both (which is correct)

```
TimeZone zone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
string standard = zone.StandardName;
string daylight = zone.DaylightName;
Console.WriteLine(standard);
Console.WriteLine(daylight);
```

Comment: I don't know the answers to this but I do know that you should probably work on how to name your variables properly ;p

Comment: @Markinson - this is just example.  When I get it working like i want the variables will have meaningful names as they are supposed to.

Comment: Have you verified that your local time is actually set to eastern time, and daylight savings is set or not set appropriately?

Comment: @TJRockefeller - yes I have.  See my edit for how I verified.

Comment: The *only* way you can be certain is to use `DateTimeOffset` with an explicit offset.

Comment: It's not due to MDT vs MST? Does eastern time have daylight savings?  Check out NodaTime too.

Comment: I just noticed that according to your values listed something is more wrong than you think. The time returned for eastern time should be two hours later, not 3 hours earlier, so you are actually off from the correct time by a lot more than you originally thought.

Comment: `iKnowThisIsUtc` is a dreadfully poorly named variable.  Convert.ToDateTime() produces local time, not UTC.  Easy to see by looking at the Kind property with the debugger.  So name it `iKnowThisIsLocal` and you'll now know to delete the next two buggy statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the string to a DateTime object:

```
var datetime = DateTime.Parse("2017-01-10T13:19:00-07:00");
```

Get the timezone for EST:

```
var easternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
```

Convert to EST (note the conversion `.ToUniversalTime()`):

```
var easternTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(datetime.ToUniversalTime(), easternZone);
```

Output of `easternTime.ToString();`:

> 10/01/2017 15:19:00

(I'm in the UK hence dd/MM/yyyy, yours may show differently)

Comment: This works, but it's not ideal.  Parsing with offset to `DateTime` switches the `Kind` to `DateTimeKind.Local`.  Then later you use the `ToUniversalTime` function to convert from local to UTC.  Really the local machine's time zone should be left out of the equation.  Also worth noting that this *will* survive DST fall-back ambiguities, but only due to [the hidden fourth `DateTimeKind`](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/05/02/more-fun-with-datetime/).  A cleaner way is with just `DateTimeOffset`, as I show in my answer.  But thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
// your input string
string green = "2017-01-10T13:19:00-07:00";

// parse to a DateTimeOffset
DateTimeOffset dto = DateTimeOffset.Parse(green);

// find the time zone that you are interested in.
// note that this one is US Eastern time - inclusive of both EST and EDT, despite the name.
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");

// convert the DateTimeOffset to the time zone
DateTimeOffset eastern = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dto, tzi);

// If you need it, you can get just the DateTime portion.  (Its .Kind will be Unspecified)
DateTime dtEastern = eastern.DateTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

When your application needs to be unambiguously aware of timezones, you may want to consider a DateTimeOffset instead of DateTime.

[Choosing Between DateTime, DateTimeOffset, TimeSpan, and TimeZoneInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384267(v=vs.110).aspx)

And this question looks like someone has collected lots of best practices on this topoic - [Daylight saving time and time zone best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices?rq=1)